# making value of form field blank if other is

Tags: javascript

I looked around and couldn't find anything like this.  I have a field that holds a date.  Next to it is one that hold the number of hours.

I need javascript to, on click, evaluate the date field, and if that's blank, automatically blank out the value of the text box to it's immediate left.

Part of the code of my form looks like this:

```
  <td>Day One:</td>
    <td width="250"> <input type=date name="dayone" onClick="document.getElementsByName('hours1')[0].value=8;" /></td>
    <td>Hours: (max 8) <input type="text" name="hours1" id="hours1" class="smalltext" ></td>
```

That onclick just populates the text field with '8' as a default.  So I almost need something that undoes that if someone changes their mind and clears out the date from the other form field.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You better keep your HTML clean and use `eventListener`-s - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EeW5a/)

***HTML***

```
<td width="250">
    <input type=date name="dayone" />
</td>
<td>
    Hours: (max 8)
    <input type="text" name="hours1" id="hours1" class="smalltext" />
</td>
```

***JS***

```
document.getElementsByName('dayone')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementsByName('hours1')[0].value = 8;
}, false);

document.getElementsByName('hours1')[0].addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    if ( this.value == '' ) {
        document.getElementsByName('dayone')[0].value = '';
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script>
   function clearinput(){
      var el = document.getElementById('hours1');
     el.value = '';
}
</script>
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTL73/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to add an onblur event handler

```
   <td width="250"> <input type=date name="dayone" onblur="checkValue" onClick="document.getElementsByName('hours1')[0].value=8;" /></td>
```

and write handler like

```
function checkValue()
{
    var dayValue = document.getElementByName('dayone')[0].value;
    if(dayValue != '')
    {
       document.getElementByName('hours1')[0].value = '';    
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `onblur="checkValue"` should be `onblur="checkValue()"`